# GraphX Pregel API: add vertices and edges

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using Spark and GraphX 2.0.2. I read that we can add vertices and edges to the graph in the vertex program (the compute() method). 
I want to know how I can add new edges and vertices using the vprog 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

What i did was keep the values as a property of the vertices and expand it after using spark flatmap function.